# How to add background-color only on some part of my page

Tags: python, html, css

I make a local page that prints me some information. My boos want to add two different colours as a background colour. I know how to add background colour to the whole page, but I don't know how to separate the page into two different background colours.
This is what my code looks like for now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pl">
    
        <head>
        
            
            <title>Raport Transmisji</title>
            
        </head>
        
        <body bgcolor=”#e6fff5">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>INSTYTUT NIEZNANY</strong></h1>
            <div>
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>DANE PRZYPADKOWE</strong></h1>
            <div>
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">ZAKŁAD NIEZNANY</h3>
            <div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">ul. Kozłowska 20, tel. 123-456-789 </div>
            <p style="text-align: center;">RAPORT TRANSMISJI DANYCH DO ## z dnia <span style="color: #ff0000;">(data)</span></p>
            <p style="text-align: center;">DO PRZEBIEGU OBLICZEŃ <span style="color: #ff0000;">(liczba)</span>/<span style="color: #ff0000;">(liczba)</span></p>
            <hr />
            <p>Łączna liczba zwierząt w aktualnej transmisji - <span style="color: #ff0000;">(liczba)</span></p>
            <hr />
            <p>CZYSTORASOWE:</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">WBP - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">PBZ - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">Puławska - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">Hampshire - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">Duroc - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <p style="text-align: justify; padding-left: 80px;">Pietrain - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)/(liczba)/(liczba)</p>
            <hr />
            
                <p>MIESZAŃCE:</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą WBP - liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to WBP(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to WBP(razem/knurki/loszki - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą PBZ- liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to PBZ(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to PBZ(razem/knurki/loszki - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą Puławską- liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to Puławska(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to Puławska(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą Hampshire- liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to Hampshire(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to Hampshire(razem/knurki/loszki - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą Duroc- liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to Duroc(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to Duroc(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w z rasą Pietrain- liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa ojca to Pietrain(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
                <p style="padding-left: 40px;">Mieszańc&oacute;w gdzie rasa matki to Pietrain(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba</p>
            
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p style="text-align: justify;font-size: 12px">DONICE, DNIA&nbsp; ..............&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;...................</p>
                <p style="font-size: 10px; padding-left: 560px;">(podpis)</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Every word "liczba" or "data" will be replaced in my python program.
This code gives me a good-looking report but I have one colour on my whole page.
I need one colour from "RAPORT TRANSMISJI DANYCH DO ## z dnia" to "Pietrain - (razem/knurki/loszki) - (liczba)(liczba)(liczba)" included this both lines.
Second colour from "MIESZAŃE" to "Mieszańców gdzie rasa matki to Pietrain(razem/knurki/loszki) - liczba/liczba/liczba" included this both lines.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Wrap each set of elements into a `div` container, and apply background-color to those ...?

Comment: There is too much complexity in your code for a simple question like "how to style background of specific html element". I'd recommended trying to design your questions to be as simple as possible so that others can find them useful / relatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different div class and apply different styles to each div particular div. eg.

```
<div class=one></div>
<div class=two></div>
```

and then in the css file

```
.one {
     background-color: yellow;
}

.two {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either divide your page into iframes using  and add different background colored webpages seperately to your mainpage or you can use the  tag to divide a section of the page and only give it a particular color defining it's css properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. change the left and right margin for the entire body to 0.
   You can define this default margin under style tag. Style tag must be defined inside head tag.

```
<style>
    *{
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
</style>
```

2. create two different div for two different colored segments. Write the
   content inside respective div and assign color to each.

```
<div class="first-half" style="background-color: blueviolet;color: white;">
Write your content here
</div>
```

Repeat the same for the second half

Comment: Please mention CSS for class `first-half`.

Comment: I already defined css using style inside div tag. However, if u intend to do the same using style tag then within it write the following:  .first-half{background-color: blueviolet; color: white;}